# Is WSUnit dead? What's the alternative?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jax-ws

I'd like to unit test a SOAP client with real HTTP requests/responses to a mock service. I've seen suggestions to use WSUnit, but all the links go to "Page Not Found" http://java.net/projects/wsunit/

What is the current industry standard to creating a mock web service for unit testing?

Comment: It appears to be rather alive. https://github.com/lapistano/wsunit

Can't comment on how good it is, only that it has recent updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/About-SoapUI/features.html), a very rich tool for testing and mocking SOAP and REST web services: functional testing, mocking and load testing.

Answer (score 0):

[WSUnit](https://github.com/lapistano/wsunit) was decleared discontinued Oct 11, 2013. If you want something which works with Mockito, try [this](https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf) simple project I've created.